# jquery auto height issue in chrome

Tags: jquery, height

[image]I've created a site which adjusts the height according to size of window screen, mean there will be no scroll. its working fine as expected, but not on chrome in windows xp even its working fine in Windows 7 in chrome.

here is [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ucZrx/).

HTML:

```
<section id="mainWrapper">
    <header>Header Content</header>
    <div>panel Content</div>        
    <footer>Footer Content</footer>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#mainWrapper {
    background: pink;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    /*padding-bottom: 50px;*/
}
header {
    background: yellow;
    height: 85px;
}
footer {
    background: orange;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    height:30px;
    width:100%;
}
div {
    background: purple;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var bodyheight = $(document).height();
$("#mainWrapper").height(bodyheight);
$("div").height($('#mainWrapper').height() - $("header").height() - $("footer").height() - 20);
```

and different browsers snapshot from [Browser Shot](http://browsershots.org/http://jsfiddle.net/ucZrx/)

I've search a lot and tried many times but couldn't fix this issue. Hope my question is clear.

Here are the screen shots that is take from chorme-windows xp.

1. [Example 1 http://api.browsershots.org/png/original/50/50a5be866ec601d18f396ff7176f8e4e.png](http://api.browsershots.org/png/original/50/50a5be866ec601d18f396ff7176f8e4e.png)
2. [Example 2 http://api.browsershots.org/png/original/19/19f5f623ac0632361674f7e4f0606f94.png](http://api.browsershots.org/png/original/19/19f5f623ac0632361674f7e4f0606f94.png)
3. [Example 3 http://api.browsershots.org/png/original/e7/e7e9bf808583080c88ea15f24e913071.png](http://api.browsershots.org/png/original/e7/e7e9bf808583080c88ea15f24e913071.png)

Answer (score 0):

The 1st image you have there is from an unsupported **CHROME 3**.

It should work in all modern browsers.

Comment: yes it should work, but unfortunately not in chrome. Even i install latest version of chrome in XP, but that issue still exist. I've added image above.

Comment: I've treid many times but no luck. So your advise will be very helpful for me. thanks